# Hibernate-validator: How do I interpolate messages with variables containing format "${...}"?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-validator

I have a hibernate-validation message that interpolates a value ${value}.

Issue is, that the value variable itself is a string of the form "${ohno}". I'd like my final interpolated message to replace ${value} with this literal string "${ohno}" but instead it seems to attempt some sort of recursive interpolation which produces the error "Cannot find property ohno".

I can't really thing of a way to "escape" this string in the message template. Perhaps I can escape it in the string itself before I pass it to the annotation but I'd rather not have to do that (I use this string as a literal elsewhere).

Does anyone know of a work around? Or perhaps I should open up a ticket with hibernate-validator...

Answer (score 1):

There is really no work around except escaping {,},\ and $ are meta characters which need to be escaped in Bean Validation. See [Message Interpolation](http://beanvalidation.org/1.1/spec/#validationapi-message) in the spec. See also [HV-934](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HV-934) in the Validator issue tracker.

Now, if you really do not want to interpolate according to the Bean Validation specification, you can write your on *MessageInterpolator* and make sure that it gets picked up during Validator initialization. Basically you need a *validation.xml* pointing out your custom interpolator. Check the docs, there are several examples how to do it.

Comment: Thanks Hardy. I was the one that actually created that ticket and responded there. I guess I don't have much choice. A custom MessageInterpolator might be overkill for me so I'll just try to escape the string.

Comment: I actually found a work around. In the message, rather than using {value} I used ${true? value: ''}. Hacky, but it works.